# Fragment opened separately from Activity doesnt show up actionbar

Tags: android, fragment, androidx

I have been using the NavigationDrawer activity. I have been calling the fragment from the activity. It gets called successfully but the actionbar is not showing up.

Code: Gallery_Frag - an activity created to extend teh fragment that i want to show up.

```
public class Gallery_Frag extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new GalleryFragment()).commit(); }
    }
```

CODE: GalleryFragment

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
       /* final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });*/
        return root;
    }}
```

CODE: manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Gallery_Frag"
    android:label="My Bookings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

CODE:app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

CODE: content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `setContentView(layoutId)` is missing in onCreate method. Can you check?

Comment: Use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` instead of `this` in fragments

Comment: @JAnandBoss added but still didnt worked

Comment: @EpicPandaForce where to add that function?

Comment: @Prajwal Please update the latest code.

Comment: Code looks clear. I believe you have declared a fragment in  `app_bar_main` layout. If yes, instead of `.add(android.R.id.content, new GalleryFragment())`  do `                  delete(android.R.id.content, new GalleryFragment())`.

Comment: Basically **add** will inflate another fragment over the existing one. **replace** is the correct one IMO.

Comment: @JAnandBoss .delete doesnt exist and .replace didnt worked for me

Comment: @PrajwalW Thats strange. Pls share the layout file `app_bar_main`

Comment: @JAnandBoss added the xml file

Comment: @PrajwalW  Still `content_main.xml` is missing dude.

Comment: As per my understanding, `android.R.id.content` indicates the full content; and when you're adding/replacing, the new fragment will be inflated over to it. You have to pass your local **content id**

Comment: @JAnandBoss have added the content_main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a container inside this `content_main.xml`;

if yes, pass that id to the `add(R.id.container_id, new GalleryFragment())...`

Otherwise change `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`  to

`<include layout="@layout/content_main" 
 android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>`

and use

`add(R.id.fragment_container, new GalleryFragment())...`

Comment: Pl check my new answer.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `android.R.id.content` indicates the full content; and when you're adding/replacing, the new fragment will occupy the full content. So we need to have a container for the fragment and replace the fragment inside the container whenever required. You did all the parts correct but missed to have a reference of the container and replacing its child.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to set `layout` to `Activity` using `setContentView` which contain `Toolbar`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set it first
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content, new GalleryFragment()).commit(); }
}
```

Comment: Add your layout

Comment: Where is your `NavigationView` layout. You are using wrong layout.

Comment: What i need to do pls mention

Answer (score 0):

**Got it**

In your `content_main.xml` file, add an id to the parent relative layout like below,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
```

And replace,

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new GalleryFragment()).commit();
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new GalleryFragment()).commit();
```

This will hopefully work.